# Computation of Posterior Mixture Weights

Tags: bayesian, stochastic-processes, mixture-distribution

My question concerns the below example, where the author analyzes rainfall occurrences via a first order Markov chain. The transition probabilities are such that $p_{11} + p_{12} = 1$ and $p_{21} + p_{22} = 1$. Beta(1/2, 1/2) priors were placed on $p_{ii}$ for $i =1 , 2$.

[image]

I see can see how the forms of both posteriors were derived, but for the life of me I can not figure our how the weights for the mixture distribution (0.44 and 0.56) of $p_{11}|\mathbf{x}$ were computed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. For future reference, it is essentially a result of integrating out $p_{22}$ and then working with the constants.